# Formal parameter type transform

Tags: java, oop

I'm quite confused about an issue I encountered while working on Java.

I created a method called `print` in class `AA` which requires three parameters: `int column`,`int row`, and `char a`.

In `main`, I invoked this method by passing three `int` values. However, the compiler says that I can't assign an `int` to `char`. I know I'm assigning an `int` value to `char`. Shouldn't implicit conversion happen when assigning an `int` to `char`?

For example:

```java
char a = 97;
```

```java
public class test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      AA aa = new AA();
      aa.print(10,5,97);
   }
}

class AA{
   public void print(int column, int row, char a){
      for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
         for(int j = 1; j <= column; j++){
            System.out.print(a);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The implicit conversion only happens when you assign a char to an int-type object. When you call

> System.out.println();
>
> System.out.print();

These methods internally call the toString() method, which changes everything that is passed inside this method to String and prints the answer as a String in the console.

So for you to get the expected result, make the following changes in the code.

Instead of

```
class AA{
   public void print(int column, int row, char a){
      for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
         for(int j = 1; j <= column; j++){
            System.out.print(a);
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Change it to

```
public class AA {
    public void print(int column, int row, char a){
        for(int i = 1; i <= row; i++){
            for(int j = 1; j <= column; j++){
                int c = a;
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

If you look closer, I have assigned a char to the int type variable and passed it into the System.out.print() method. This will implicitly convert char to its corresponding ASCII value and it will provide you the desired result. The conversion happens in this place `int c = a;`

For more clarification: [Implicit Type Casting](https://www.javatpoint.com/implicitly-typecasting-in-java#:%7E:text=The%20process%20of%20converting%20one,type%20casting%20or%20widening%20casting.)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But if I assign a int constant to char, for example, char a = 97; 
The complier won't generate error, because char is stored as number in JVM.
Based on this idea, I want to assign a int to a formal parameter which its type is char and get a error this time.
Chould you please tell me why?

Comment: What you're asking is logically correct, but that's not how the Java print method works. You're seeing the print method as a variable to which you're assigning the values. See it's a method, the Java `System.out.print() and Println()` is an overloaded method which only accepts (boolean, char, int, long, float, double, char[], String and object) type arguments. So when you pass in an int value during a method call it calls the method that accepts the int type parameter, which then internally calls String.valueOf() method which calls Integer.toString() method. These are overloaded methods too.

Comment: There are no implicit conversions happening in these methods.  You can also see it for yourself If you're using any IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse. Just hold Control then left-click the word print in the `System.out.print()` method or please check [printStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Shouldn't implicit conversion happen when assigning an int to char? ..."*

No, only from a *char* to an *int*.

*[Java Language Specification – 5.3. Method Invocation Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3)*.

> *"Method invocation conversions specifically do not include the implicit narrowing of integer constants which is part of assignment conversion ..."*

Thus, since a *char* is a two byte value, a plausible loss of information may occur.

Comment: But how "char a = 97;" work?

Comment: I believe that is because it's an assignment.  When you're passing the value to the parameter, it's a different context for the compiler,  _https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2_.  Similar to trying to assign a value too large for an int; _int value = 12345678901;_.  It can infer if the data type can hold the value.

Answer (score 0):

An implicit conversion from `int` to `char` only occurs if the value is a compile-time constant known to fit within a `char` (and only in an assignment context).

This is defined in [section 5.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) of the Java Language Specification, which writes:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.29) of type `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `int`:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the variable is of type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.